# Homework: Array splitting in C programming

Tags: c

Why does my coding stop after print "Enter a for aligned or i for indented"?

I've already tried separating the code, like the way the coding would be read/processed, and asked my friends that are also in this class what I'm doing wrong....please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MaxSize 1024
void split(char array[], int start, int length);
void splitAndMove(char array[], int start, int length);
int main(){
    int n,i;
    char ch;
    char string[MaxSize];
    printf("Enter the number of character:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the character array:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%c", &string[i]);
        printf("Enter a for aligned or i for indented:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if(ch == 'a')
           split(string, 0, n);
        else if(ch == 'i')
           splitAndMove(string, 0, n);
        return 0;
    }
}
void split(char array[], int start, int length){
    if (start >= length){
        return;
    }
    printf("*%c*\n", array[start]);
    split(array, start+1, length);
}
void splitAndMove(char array[], int start, int length){
    int i;
    if(start >= length){
        return;
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= start;i++){
         printf(" ");
    }
    printf("*%c*\n", array[start]);
    splitAndMove(array, start+1, length);
}
```

I should expect the result to look like:

```
*H*
 *E*
  *L*
   *P*
```

when i is input and:

```
*H*
*E*
*L*
*P*
```

when a is input

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior. Find out if your compiler supports it before using it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/6699433

Comment: Also, check the return value of scanf.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your for loop block after asking for the character array.

Also change `scanf("%c", ...)` to `scanf(" %c, ...)` since `"%c"` does not remove trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just done some modification in code instead of `scanf("%c",&ch);` used `scanf(" %c",&ch);`

Removed `fflush(stdin);` and done some changes in length and also removed for loop as there was no need of loop as u can take string input with `%s`
in scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MaxSize 1024
void split(char array[], int start, int length);
void splitAndMove(char array[], int start, int length);
int main(){
    int n,i;
    char ch;
    char string[MaxSize];
    printf("Enter the number of character:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the character array:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("Enter a for aligned or i for indented:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    if(ch == 'a')
        split(string, 0, n);
    else if(ch == 'i')
        splitAndMove(string, 0, n);
    return 0;
}
void split(char array[], int start, int length){
    if (start >= length){
        return;
    }
    printf("*%c*\n", array[start]);
    split(array, start+1, length);
}
void splitAndMove(char array[], int start, int length){
    int i;
    if(start >= length){
        return;
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= start;i++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("*%c*\n", array[start]);
    splitAndMove(array, start+1, length);
}
```

Comment: What is `i` when `scanf("%s", &string[i]);` is called?  `scanf("%1023s", string);` makes more sense.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= start;i++){
        printf(" ");
    }` is replaceable with `printf("%*s", start + 1, "");`